# JDK Location on Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android

When android studio installed on my laptop, I received notification that said `Invalid Project JDK`, and then it asked me to change the location path of JDK on Android Studio.

Okay, then I changed that into this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66
```

When I clicked `OK`, it's still there! I open my settings, and I found that my jdk location path unchanged:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
```

It cannot save my new location path.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path to C:\Users\me.AndroidStudio1.4\config\options\jdk.table.xml
and reload Android Studio.